# Dynamic Log Based Metric and Alert Policy

Tags: logging, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create a dynamic log-based metric that retrieves the Current Date records based on timestamp. On top of it, I could create the Alert Policy to ensure that some specific activity is conducted today.

Something like

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
timestamp > "Today"
```

Any one who can help me in this?

Comment: do you mean, you want to only see the metrics for today ?

Comment: I want to see if the log entry is there for a specific time range on daily basis or not. I believe Timestamp is the only attribute that can be used to do so.
For instance, between 3AM- 4AM but date has to be dynamic like in SQL we have CURDATE, NOW, SYSDATE so that it doesn't perform calculation on constant date.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add that query in the filter field  .

Reference code is below

[image]